# How to update the table with different value in Oracle based on iteration

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I would like to update the table in Oracle with a different value for the 1st iteration or 1st item. I'm not sure how I can do that.

For example I would like the 1st iteration or 1st to update as:

```
UPDATE PRODUCTS SET INFO = 'RELATED PRODUCTS' || RELATED_PRODUCT_ID || ',';
COMMIT;
```

and the following iterations to only include the RELATED PRODUCT_ID as follows:

```
UPDATE PRODUCTS SET INFO = RELATED_PRODUCT_ID || ',';
COMMIT;
```

Thank you so much for your time and help in advance!

Comment: What is an *iteration*? Please provide sample data and expected results to help us understand.

Comment: Which record should be considered as the firat record? What should be the ordering?

Comment: What you are trying to do does not seem to make sense. This is not the kind of the data that a table should hold.

Comment: It is with regards to this question, in the update statement I would like to have a different value for the 1st update operation. I can't make use of the NVL function as this field may already have data present within it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60569569/how-do-i-convert-these-sql-statements-into-more-efficient-statements

Comment: I'd suggest you update your post to include a representative CREATE TABLE statement, followed by a representative INSERT statement(s).  However, it certainly looks like you are trying to create/maintain a comma-delimited list within a single column. If so, this flies in the face of every rule of rdbms design.  Google 'data normalization', 'first normal form','second normal form', and 'third normal form'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about your requirement but as far as I understood, You can use case when as following:

```
UPDATE PRODUCTS SET INFO = 
    CASE WHEN INSTR(INFO,'RELATED PRODUCTS') = 1 
         THEN RELATED_PRODUCT_ID 
         ELSE 'RELATED PRODUCTS' || RELATED_PRODUCT_ID || ',' 
     END;
COMMIT;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you so much Tejash, I was able to achieve what I was aiming for using your solution.